# After passing data from one function to another, the data is not getting saved in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am passing a data variable from one function to another in my controller. It is getting passed successfully but when I am trying to use it in an if statement in the second function I am getting undefined variable error.

Here is my function number 1

```
public function otp()
    {
        //$this->input->post('email') ;
        //print_r($data['POST']);
        //exit();
        //$this->load->view('login/otp');       
        $success = "";
        $error_message = "";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fame");
        if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {

            $email = $_POST["email"];//I want to send this data
            //print_r($email);
            //exit();
            $this -> validate_otp($email);// I am sending the data here
    }
```

Here is my function number 2

```
public function validate_otp($email) // Line 90
    {
    print_r($email);// Data is getting printed here
    exit(); //If I do this then the data is getting printed correctly upto this point. Once it gets into the below if statement it is showing the errors. 

    if ($this->agent->is_browser())
                {
                        $browser = $this->agent->browser().' '.$this->agent->version();
                        //echo $browser;
                        $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
                        //echo $ip;
                        $platform = $this->agent->platform();
                        $data = array(
                            'username' => $email,//Here this is getting undefined variable error (Line 120)
                            'browser' => $this->agent->browser().' '.$this->agent->version(),
                            'platform' => $this->agent->platform(),
                            'ip' => $this->input->ip_address()                          
                        );


                        $this->Login_info_model->add_record($data);
                        echo "You are successfully logged";
                        //exit();
                }
}
```

I am not understanding the reason why I am not able to read the variable in the if statement of the second function after passing the data variable successfully. Any help will be most welcome. Thanks in advance.

[image: This is the error]

[image: This is the second error]

My Login_info_model

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_info_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function add_record($data){

        $this->db->insert('tab_login_info',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting error due to `$email`? Can you give it a try by commenting out the line : `'username' => $email,` within the array?

Comment: can you show us the values inside `$email`  in both postions?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay When I comment out that part, all the other data is getting stored in database

Comment: @ShobiPP $email in both places have this value -> abc@xyz.com (It is an username)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seams you'r printing the wrong variable when you did this:

```
public function validate_otp($email)
    {
    print_r($data);// Data is getting printed here
```

What happens if you do this?

```
public function validate_otp($email)
    {
    print_r($email);// Data is getting printed here
```

Another thing, there's something missing here:

```
public function otp()
    {
        //$this->input->post('email') ;
        //print_r($data['POST']);
        //exit();
        //$this->load->view('login/otp');       
        $success = "";
        $error_message = "";
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fame");
        if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {

            $email = $_POST["email"];//I want to send this data
            //print_r($email);
            //exit();
            $this -> validate_otp($email);// I am sending the data here
**} ->>> This was missing**
    }
```